# How to encode IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifier) to actual text in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, iri

actual URL - `http://localhost:3000/यह-दुकान-है`

this URL is converted to IRI - `http://localhost:3000/%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88`

**Is there any possibility to convert it back to real URL from IRI in NextJs ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get IRI to actual text from `decodeURI()` in nextJS.

*for example :*

```js
const convertedUrl = decodeURI("http://localhost:3000/%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88")
console.log(convertedUrl)
```